# Is this 'new releases in SF&F' question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41032/1027) has been closed, (not edited) and then reopened, and is now getting close votes again.  One user even voted to both close and reopen it.  Seems like we don't know what to do with this question.  The main thrust of it is:

> Where do you guys find out about recently published novels in Science Fiction and Fantasy?
>
> I'm not interested in reviews, news on which writer might write what, which bookstore has closed, conventions etc., just a simple list of everything that is newly available in bookstores.

They're looking for resources that provide thorough listings of Sci-fi & Fantasy book releases.  Is this on topic, or off topic?  Why?

Comment: What does an upvote or a downvote on this meta question mean? If I think the original question was on topic, am I supposed to vote up or down?

Comment: @user14111 - if a meta question doesn't offer an **opinion** (which this one does not IMHO), you should merely vote on whether it was interesting and/or a good idea to ask it. (this is different when the question contains an opinion/idea/proposal - then meta convention is to vote up/down as far as agreeing/disagreeing)

Answer (score 5):

I think the question is fine.

The scope is well-defined, and it doesn't seem likely that there will be so many answers that we'd risk a lot of "me too" answers.

While there could be several different yet acceptable, answers, I  don't think that's sufficient reason to close it.

The subject itself is both relevant and of potential interest to a significant number of our members.

Comment: It's answerable, relevant, and an interesting question.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like an unanswerable question. Sure, a few good sites could be recommended, but in the end, any number of answers could be equally acceptable. Given that possibility, it seems like it's not really a good question for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Does this mean that, if there is one and only one site that performs the desired function, the question is acceptable; but if there are many such sites, the question is unacceptable? (So the criteria require one to **know the answer** to the question in order to decide whether it's on topic?) Or are you saying that, even if the question has a unique answer in the "real world", the fact that it **could** have multiple answers (in some possible world) makes it off topic? In the case of the actual question under discussion, what would be an "equally acceptable" alternative to isfdb.org?

Comment: Even if there are several good answers, would it be a good candidate for a Community Wiki answer, which combines these equally-good answers into one?